# How is Sketch linked to Mobile Web Development?

Tags: user-interface, react-native, user-experience

I am new to both Mobile App Development and Sketch and I am having a hard time understanding how Sketch can be used in developing a mobile application.

I am looking into React-Native to develop an application, but from my understanding, the only way you can style elements in React is through a css file and I don't see how I can use Sketch to design my app.

Am I totally missing something or is it possible to develop an application in React-Native and use Sketch to design the elements in the app?

Thanks!

Comment: Sketch is only for designers. You can't convert sketch designs into React components.
And just to clarify, React Native doesn't use CSS, because it's not the browser who runs the apps, but the property names are very similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does that mean front-end developers manually style their websites/application to mimic the UI design created in Sketch?

Comment: Exactly. The designers make each screen in Sketch with typographies, colors, spaces, margins and all those things you need, and you developer try to mimic them with the same values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch is a design tool just like Photoshop or illustrator. But its is far better then both the tools for multiple reason

It creates design which only code possible. Where Photoshop is originally created for photo editing, many of the effects which you could create there can't be created by codes.

It is very simple have tools which are only required for UI design. No brush tool, Smudge tool etc.

Vector based tool you can export any asset as svg or copy the codes.

You can also copy the styling as CSS and use. No style document required.

You can prototype a interactive model ad test it before you code. This is the biggest advantage, you can actually test the application before you invest time on coding it.

Open file format. Many third party tool can read the sketch file and you can extend you design to the next level. For example you can upload the prototype in InVision and share the design as a cloud link

These are some of the reason why you should chose sketch. But otherwise it is just another design tool. It can't create the functional app for you.

Answer (score 1):

There're several tools that focus on the conversion from the design file into the mobile app.

- Supernova - sketch to react native & native app
- BuilderX - sketch to react/react native
- XD to flutter - you can import sketch into XD and convert into flutter App
- pxCode - the solution we have developed, turn the sketch into react/react native

This area is relatively new because the design file is not well-structured in terms of the code. So that's why the mapping is so hard and the code quality is not easy to keep.
That's why after quite a few iterations and analsysi, we find the key structure should leave for the frontend engineers' experience and professional to solve instead of automating the task